# How do I create a simple on-mouse-click rotating object in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This question may get downvoted or go unanswered because it's not the greatest and incredible silly but anyway,

I'm taking an intro level Webanimation course this semester at UNI and had I know what their expectations are for our hand-in projects i would have never taken it up.

Basically the teacher taught us stuff to the extent of masking/tweening and very few mouse-event and basic function codes.

Now she is expecting us to make a god damn ENTIRE PIPE GAME. The one where there are a bunch of rotating pipes and you gotta rotate them in place before a timer runs out and then the water flows through them.

For this project I have to somehow figure out the following (even though she didn't teach any of this):

-creature a grid of rotate-able pipes (one mouse click I assume would do a 90 degree classic tween rotation of the object)

-creature some sort of logic hit-box value chain to make pipes decide when to fill with water (they fill with water (a.k.a turn blue inside as an animation) once they are connected to another water filled pipe, for example)

-creature multiple levels and a menu screen

-add a music track.

**Now i know this site is for specific help only and you basically can't ask for help on an entire project, so for now if somebody could just help me out with the following:**

**How do I create a rotating pipe on mouseclick?**

So I have my pipe movieclip created and I have my Mouse Event code ready but I don't have the faintest on how to make a tween within the pipe and connect it to the code so that it rotates on mouseclick.

So this far, let's say for one of the pipes, instance pipe_1, I want to do this:

```
pipe_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Mouse clicked");
}
```

I also have the simple tween of rotation already created within the instance of the pipe, but dunno how to connect it to code.

I'm supposed to figure out what to put inside the function but I honestly have no clue. Hours of googling have come up with nothing either except a 12 dollar purchasable source code for an even more complicated pipe game.

I hope somebody can at least help a bit, and thanks.

Comment: Next time, just ask the question, without the life story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to rotate a clip is via it's `rotation` property. It defaults to 0.

If you were set the `rotation` property of your tile to 90, you'd rotate your pipe tile 90 degrees.

for example :

`pipe_1.rotation += 90;`

A tween is a means of changing a property of a given DisplayObject over time. So what you want to do is tween your rotation property 90 degrees over time.

Here is a tutorial on Tweening - http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3tweenclass/

I think it'd be more beneficial for you to take the time to learn about it, than to have me just write a few lines of code to solve your problem.

StackOverflow is a place where you can ask a question, AFTER you have tried something and have hit an issue.

I have provided you with the basic concept of what you need to do, and if you take the time to learn about tweening, you'll be able to achieve your goal rather simply.

There are also tweening libraries such as TweenLite and TweenMax that simplify tweening. Not sure if your class will allow you to use them, but worthwhile to check out for your own benefit.

You can find TweenLite here :
http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a frame by frame tween? or tweening with code?

for frame by frame tweening, you can try to do this:

```
pipe_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f1_MouseClickHandler);
function f1_MouseClickHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
   pipe_1.gotoAndPlay(2); //if the tween starts at frame 2
}
```

For code tweening, just call the tween function inside that handler function